# WPF: Binding custom class to datagrid using mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf

I would like to bind my user class to my data grid using mysql.

This is my User.cs:

```
public class User
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string UserPassword { get; set; }
    public string UserEmail { get; set; }
    public string UserFirstName { get; set; }
    public string UserLastName { get; set; }
}
```

This is my viewuser.xaml:

```
 public view_users(string loginName)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        List<User> user = new List<User>();

        btnSave.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        labelLogin = loginName;
        labelLoginName.Content = labelLogin;

        string query;
        query = "select * from users";
        da = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, db.GetConnection());
        da.Fill(dt);

        userDataGrid.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;


    }
```

I dont know how to proceed to bind my user class to the data grid. All the examples are using without mysql. Can someone help me.

Comment: it is completely irrelevant that data was queried from MySQL table. UI and DataAccess are separated by more that one layers of abstraction

Answer (score 0):

In your Xaml bind the items source to user. (I would rename to UserList, or something to indicate a collection)

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding UserList}" />
```

Then populate the user list from the DataTable.

I usually do this by creating a constructor that takes a DataRow.

```
public class User
{
    public User(rw)
    {
       UserName = rw["UserName"].ToString();
       UserPassword = rw["UserPassword"].ToString();
       UserEmail = rw["UserEmail"].ToString();
       UserFirstName = rw["UserFirstName "].ToString();
       UserLastName = rw["UserLastName"].ToString();
    }

    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string UserPassword { get; set; }
    public string UserEmail { get; set; }
    public string UserFirstName { get; set; }
    public string UserLastName { get; set; }
}
```

Then the list can be populated like this: (I would use an ObservableCollection instead).

```
public ObservableCollection<User> GetUsers()
{
    var UserList = new ObservableCollection<User>();
    string query;
    query = "select * from users";
    da = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, db.GetConnection());
    da.Fill(dt);
    foreach (DataRow rw in dt.Rows) { UserList.Add(new User(row)); }        
    return UserList;
}
```